# Reloading of deleted list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input box which you can enter items, submit it, and create a box with it's own delete button to remove it. Problem is, after deleting a number of boxes, and then entering something new in input, all the previous items that were deleted get reloaded, including the new item.
How can I prevent reloading of already removed boxes?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkanf6r5/) (Stacksnippets do not allow submit)

This is my Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Shopping List Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css-list.css"> 
</head>
<div id="centerPanel">  
<form class="my-list-form">     

    <input type="text" class="input" name="add-input" id="add-input">    

     <button class="add-button" id="submitBtn">Add</button>
</form>
<ul class="my-list-ul"></ul>
</div>  

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js-list.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var state = {items:[]};
var addItem = function(state, item)
{
state.items.push(item);
}
var displayItem = function(state, element){
var htmlItems = state.items.map(function(item){
    return '<li class="box">' + item + '</br><button class="divBtns"       id="deleteBtn">Delete</button>' + '</li>'; 
});
element.html(htmlItems);
}
//After deleting items, this button again loads all items that have been  created since
//the page loaded up, including the new item.
//Needs to be fixed to not reload the deleted items
$('.my-list-form').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
addItem(state, $('.input').val());
displayItem(state, $('.my-list-ul') );
/* alert(state.items[1]);           shows that the items array holds everything that is turned into a div*/ 
})

$(document).ready(function(e){              
$('ul').on('click', '#deleteBtn', function(event){
    var rmvButton = $(this).closest('li');
    rmvButton.remove();
});
})
```

css:

```
* {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
}
#centerPanel {
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
padding-left: 10px;

}
h1 {
font-size: 34px;

}
.font-size {
font-size: 17px;
}
#add-input {
height:25px;
width: 190px;
font-size: 16px;
}
button {
font-size: 17px;
}
#submitBtn {
height: 30px;
width: 85px;
}
.divBtns {
margin-top: 10px;
}
.box {
border: 1px solid black;
border-color: grey;
width: 153px;
height: 65px;
padding: 20px;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 22px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-left:-40px;
color: grey;
}
li {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Apart from deleting from the array you create, you need also to change the `'#deleteBtn` to a class like I did in the JSFiddle I created for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you never remove anything from the `state` object, which is added to every time you run `addItem()`.

You'd need a way to remove a specific item from this array, probably by getting the index of the `li` to delete and doing

```
state.items.splice(index, 1);
```

Store the index as a data attribute on the button:

```
var displayItem = function(state, element){
    var i = 0;
    var htmlItems = state.items.map(function(item){
        return '<li class="box">' + item + '</br><button class="divBtns" ' +
          'id="deleteBtn" data-index="' + (i++) + '">Delete</button>' + '</li>'; 
    });
    element.html(htmlItems);
}
```

Then you can get it in the click callback

```
var index = $(this).data('index');
```

Comment: I just did! :-)

Comment: Or `var rmvButton = $(this).closest('li'), idx = rmvButton.index()`

Comment: Assuming nothing else manipulates the DOM between the list being generated and a user clicking a remove button, yes.

Comment: Thanks! Initially put    var index = $(this).data('index'); BEFORE    state.items.splice(index, 1); and it didn't work. Now it's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can update state to solve this problem.

It's my code:

```js
...

var deleteItem = function(state, itemId) {
    var index = 0;
    var isFind = state.items.some(function(item, i) {
    if (item.id == itemId) {
        index = i;
        return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (isFind) {
    state.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

...

$(document).ready(function(e){              
  $('ul').on('click', '#deleteBtn', function(event){
      ...

      // update state
      deleteItem(state, $(this).parent().data('id'));
  });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q483cLp9/